# rsa - calculating plaintext from ciphertext

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

I was solving a crypto question but now I am stuck for a long time. 
I have to calculate plaintext, when I am given ciphertext, n, and e only. How to do so?
I don't have the totient otherwise it would have become easy.

ciphertext: `107524013451079348539944510756143604203925717262185033799328445011792760545528944993719783392542163428637172323512252624567111110666168664743115203791510985709942366609626436995887781674651272233566303814979677507101168587739375699009734588985482369702634499544891509228440194615376339573685285125730286623323`

e = `3`

n = `27566996291508213932419371385141522859343226560050921196294761870500846140132385080994630946107675330189606021165260590147068785820203600882092467797813519434652632126061353583124063944373336654246386074125394368479677295167494332556053947231141336142392086767742035970752738056297057898704112912616565299451359791548536846025854378347423520104947907334451056339439706623069503088916316369813499705073573777577169392401411708920615574908593784282546154486446779246790294398198854547069593987224578333683144886242572837465834139561122101527973799583927411936200068176539747586449939559180772690007261562703222558103359`

I am not able to solve this for finding plaintext... i know i am missing something. Could you please help?

Comment: `[n,e]` is effectively a public key. By default you should have no means to reveal the ciphertext.  If it's an excercise, it may have some weakness left on purpose, see how could incorrect implementations be exploited http://members.tripod.com/irish_ronan/rsa/attacks.html

Comment: @gusto2 This is an exercise..

Comment: @gusto2 please check.. i have updated the question

Comment: I know what we're missing ... all the context for the problem.

Comment: @James K Polk this in the entire question. Would there have been another hint, I would have figured a way out.

Comment: We only require d if we see the formula.

Comment: Hint: e=3 is secure for secure padding schemes. Note that this is only about crypto and therefore questions like these should be posted on https://crypto.stackexchange.com. However posting there should be started by looking for dupes and then describing what you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: maybe as a duplicate https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6770/cracking-an-rsa-with-no-padding-and-very-small-e